# Django, ForeignKey relation, and Q or

Tags: python, django, django-models, relation, django-q

I have some problem. Consider this data schema in DB (for simplicity I omit some things):

```
class Table1(Model):
   field1;
   field2;
   table2 = ForeignKey('Table2');

class Table2(Model):
   filed3;
```

Now sample data:

```
Table2:
{ id:1, field3: lola }
{ id:2, field3: disney }

Table1:
{ id:1, field1: foo, field2: bar, table2_id: 1 }
{ id:2, field1: lola, field2: bars, table2_id: null }
```

And main part:

SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.field3 
FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table2_id=t2.id 
WHERE t1.field1 ILIKE '%lola%' OR t2.field3 ILIKE '%lola%';
```

Will result in two rows form Table1: id=1 and id=2.

Now I would like the same from django but when i try:

```
Table1.objects.filter( Q(filed1__icontains="lola") | Q(table2__filed3__icontains="lola") );
```

it returns only id=1 because table2_id is null on row with id=2.

It excludes row with id=2 because it fails on second Q.
How can I get two rows from Django in that case?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the database schema is created not by means of django-orm. In your case Django make `INNER JOIN`. Use:

```
table2 = ForeignKey('Table2', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I think it should be ForeignKey('Table2', blank=True, null = True)